# How do I get the data from a document in a collection in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with React Native and Firestore and having a lot of trouble getting the value of the name (Steve Jobs) from my Firestore document. I would like to set my displayName state to Steve Jobs. I am able to add documents and subcollections just fine to Firestore, but my problem is reading from it. I've included a simplified version of my code.

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import firebase from "../../firebase/fbConfig";

const ProfileHeader = () => {
    const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState(null);

    const UID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    let db = firebase.firestore();

    useEffect(() => {
    // get the name Steve Jobs from the document with UID in the users collection

    });

    return (
        <>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <Text>{displayName}</Text>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
};

export default ProfileHeader;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. If anyone runs into a similar problem here is the solution:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import firebase from "../../firebase/fbConfig";

const ProfileHeader = () => {
    const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState([]);

    const UID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    let db = firebase.firestore();

    const getData = async () => {
        const snapshot = await db.collection("users").doc(UID).get();

        setDisplayName(snapshot.data());
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <Text>{displayName.name}</Text>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
};

export default ProfileHeader;
```